# Kivy - ValueError: Image.source accept only str

Tags: python, kivy

I have this screen in my code and I get the following error:

```
kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\siuba\Documents\GitHub\Art-Photo-Mirror-V2\ui.kv", line 138:
 ...
     136:                
     137:                Image:
 >>  138:                    source: "Assets/UI/Printing/Print.png",
     139:                    size_hint: (.1, .05),
     140:                    pos_hint: {'x': .48, 'y': .47}
 ...
 ValueError: Image.source accept only str
```

This is my code:

```
Screen:
    name: "copies_selection"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Copies: 1",
            font_size: 75,
            font_name: "SegoeUI",
            pos_hint: {'x': .30, 'y': .49}
            
        Image:
            source: "Assets/UI/Printing/Plus.png",
            size_hint: (.1, .05),
            pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .50}
            
        Image:
            source: "Assets/UI/Printing/Minus.png",
            size_hint: (.1, .05),
            pos_hint: {'x': .35, 'y': .43}
        
        Image:
            source: "Assets/UI/Printing/Print.png",
            size_hint: (.1, .05),
            pos_hint: {'x': .48, 'y': .47}
```

What's the problem with the code?
Any help is appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: I haven't worked with Kivy before, but as far as I can tell from [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets), property values don't have commas after them. Delete the trailing commas and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't supposed to have commas between the values. Remove the commas and you should be good :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).